# How can I change the .env file in production in React Vite applications?

Tags: reactjs, vite, dotenv

I have a couple of settings in my `.env.production` file in my Vite React project.

I built the project and deployed it on the server.

This is the content of the `.env.production`:

```
VITE_API_URL=https://api.admin.example.com
VITE_SITE_URL=https://example.com
VITE_ACCOUNTS_URL=https://accounts.example.com
VITE_ACCOUNTS_REALM=Production
VITE_ACCOUNTS_CLIENT=AdminPanel
```

Now I want to change the `VITE_API_URL` from to `https://api.admin.another-domain.tld`.

How can I do that? I can't find the `.env.production` in my built directory.

I searched for the `.env.production` but I could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to change the env settings on the server in the compiled files.
You may need to change the url in `.env.production` and run the app build again. Then redeploy its build to the server. It's the easiest way.
After compiling the files into .js, it is difficult to change the env.

Comment: This does not help me at all.

Comment: Have you tried change the value in the `.env` and then rebuilding the application? Then the URL at VITE_API_URL was still not changed?

Comment: I don't want to rebuild the application. That's the whole point.